# Не удается зарегистрироваться как разработчик в Instagram

Tags: instagram

По ссылке: https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ ввожу номер телефона, описание и ссылку на сайт: как только не пробовал и с http и https и без. Выдает ошибку:

> Error saving your changes. The URL you entered is considered unsafe
>   and may not be used.

С подсвечиванием поля Сайта. В чем же проблема? Может быть это связано с обновлениями и недавними сбоями самого Инстаграмма?

Comment: В консоли браузера (или, к примеру, Firebug) какие-нибудь дополнительные данные об ошибке выводятся? [**Здесь**](http://kristinita.ru/Sasha-Black) также можете проверить URL сайта. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос отпадает, не решен, теоретически надо настроить правильный https. А для меня уже не нужен там кабинет, нашел другое решение, для моей потребности.